# How can I prove a basic inequality in dependant type language

Tags: void, idris, inequality, negation

I would like to define the following function in idris, to learn how to deal with negation:

```
absurdity : 0 = 1 -> Void
absurdity = ?how
```

How can I do it ?

Could I just create an empty lambda and let the compiler figure out that this is not equal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `impossible`:

```hs
absurdity : 0 = 1 -> Void
absurdity Refl impossible
```

Comment: This keyword is not well documented enough, and it is a shame. But thanks !